# How can I create a Coincidence Matrix in R using R Studio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to create a conincidence matrix using R Studio for a decision tree that I have generated. I have done the same in SPSS but am not able to figure out how to do the same in R. I am attaching an image of how it looks in SPSS. If you could point me to the right resource or link that can tell me what the quivalent of this in R is, that would be very helpful. Thank you!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please try and ask targeted questions.  What have you tried?  What packages have you explored?  Where are you getting stuck?

Nonetheless, I would start by reading through this, [A Short Introduction to the **caret** Package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.pdf). Then, do this:

```
install.packages("caret")
library(caret)
?confusionMatrix
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I did not know which library to even start with or what it was called in R. I guess its called a confusionMatrix. Thanks for your help!